# Fixed navbar doesn't work properly?

Tags: css, html, blogs, blogger

I'm newbie to blogger. I got a 3rd-party template and made changes to the navibar on the main homepage that *when scroll its color changes to blue and links to White.*

But on [Posts Page](http://gaza0news.blogspot.com/2018/03/governorate-protection-focal-point.html)  the color of the links on Scroll don't change. I mean, When you scroll, the navibar links don't change to white as the main homepage, why ? I tried to change the color of links of the fixed navibar{on posts page} but it doesn't apply at all.

[image: Posts page NaviBar]

[image: Posts Page Fixed Navibar]

Here is the code of the links that i want it to change to white while scrolling down:

```
.item .menu-secondary li a, 
.static_page .menu-secondary li a {
            color: #484848;
```

Comment: Have you looked in the inspector to see what rule is setting it?

Comment: show code so we know what you've tried -

Comment: also why do you want a header that changes its background color? seems rather... meh?

Comment: .item .menu-secondary li a,
.static_page .menu-secondary li a {
    color: #484848;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your custom css in customizer.

```
.item header .logo h1 a, .static_page header .logo h1 a {
    color: #FFF;
}

.item .menu-secondary li a, .static_page .menu-secondary li a {
    color: #FFF;
}
```

For more RGBA colours you can click [here](https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_picker.asp)

Comment: Ok, you are also trying to help me changing my Navibar to white but its not my problem. Help me change the color of the Links on the (Posts Page Fixed Navibar)

Comment: I did that before. You sloved the sticky navibar but broke it when its on the top. I need links to be Black at the top, changes to White while scroll looool.
anyway it's better than nothing. :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.fixed-nav {
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 999999;
    position: fixed;
    background: white!important;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

Comment: I don't want to change the color of the navi bar.
I want to change - LINKS- color to White on Posts Page Fixed Navibar Only.

The coder of the template coded two navibars, one to the main page and the second to the Posts Page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.item #navbar:not(.fixed-nav) .menu-secondary li a, 
.static_page #navbar:not(.fixed-nav) .menu-secondary li a {
    color: #484848;
}
```